# Cayley for SL group

Tags: graphs-and-networks, group-theory

In this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2210.02997.pdf), they are using an expander graph. It seems like it's just a Cayley graph for $SL(2,Z_p)$, where $P$ is a prime number.

How do I go about making a Cayley graph as shown in the first of the algorithm using mathematica. Mathematica `CayleyGraph` seems to only support certain kinds of graph.

Comment: Could you please provide more details, e.g. examples of Mathematica code or graphs that `CayleyGraph` doesn’t support?

Comment: `CayleyGraph` function takes a group. However, mathematica doesn't have (or I couldn't find) Special Linear (SL) group : https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/NamedGroups.html

Comment: It doesn’t have to be a _named_ group though, does it? Does this help: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PermutationGroups.html?

Comment: It might. But how do I construct an SL group in Mathematica?

Comment: Cayley graph is determined by the presentation (generators + relations) of the group; two different presentation of the same group usually gives non-isomorphic Cayley graphs. So you need to specify a presentation, not just the group.

Comment: Isn't the SL group generated by matrices with $\det(m) = 1$ ?

Comment: It's a group of 2X2 matrices with determinant 1.

Answer (score 2):

Generating the Cayley graph for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$ can be done by brute force. As you point out[`CayleyGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CayleyGraph.html) does special cases with nice structure.

For what its worth, here is a brute force way for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z}_3)$.

If I have made errors (conceptual or otherwise) I will happily delete.

**The elements of the group**

```
mat = Select[Mod[Det@#, 3] == 1 &][
   Partition[#, 2] & /@ Tuples[Range[0, 2], 4]];
```

**Some vertex labeling functions**

```
rule = Thread[Range[24] -> mat];
irule = Reverse /@ rule;
```

**The generators for the group**

```
s = {{0, 2}, {1, 0}};
t = {{1, 1}, {0, 1}};
```

Note s is order 4 and t is order 3.

**Creating Cayley graph**

```
def[u_] := DirectedEdge @@@ Partition[u, 2, 1]
tup = Tuples[{s, t}, 7];
orb = FoldList[Mod[#1 . #2, 3] &, #] /. irule & /@ tup;
g = Union[Join @@ (def /@ orb)];
```

**Visualizing the graph**

```
HighlightGraph[g, 
 Join @@ {Style[#, Green] & /@ FindCycle[g, {4}, All], 
   Style[#, Red] & /@ FindCycle[g, {3}, All]}, 
 VertexLabels -> Thread[Range[24] -> MatrixForm /@ mat]]
```

[image]

The green arrows are the action of s and the red arrows actions of t.

```
GraphPlot3D[g]
```

[image]

Comment: A good code is a commented code. Your construction of the Cayley graph is very poorly  commented. For example, from where are the generators known? I think the construction is done by hand with Mathematica as a pen

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. The $SL(2,Z_p)$ group can be created as follows. This is the set

```
sl[2, p_] :=  Select[Partition[Partition[Flatten[Table[{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {a, 0, p - 1}, {b, 0, p - 1}, {c, 
   0, p - 1}, {d, 0, p - 1}]], 2], 2], Mod[Det[#], p] == 1 &]
```

with the multiplication defined by `Mod[k.n],p]`. For example,

```
sl[2, 3]
```

> `{{0, 1}, {2, 0}}, {{0, 1}, {2, 1}}, {{0, 1}, {2, 2}}, {{0, 2}, {1,  0}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}, {{1, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{1,  0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 0}, {2, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {1,  2}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 0}}, {{1, 2}, {0, 1}}, {{1, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{1,  2}, {2, 2}}, {{2, 0}, {0, 2}}, {{2, 0}, {1, 2}}, {{2, 0}, {2,  2}}, {{2, 1}, {0, 2}}, {{2, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{2, 1}, {2, 0}}, {{2,  2}, {0, 2}}, {{2, 2}, {1, 0}}, {{2, 2}, {2, 1}}}`

and

```
Mod[ {{1, 2}, {2, 2}}. {{2, 0}, {0, 2}},3]
```

> `{{2, 1}, {1, 1}}`

Its Cayley graph is huge and unuseful for big values of `p`. In my opinion (and not only in my one) most of modern mathematics is useless scholasticism.

Comment: Thank you. Isn't the determinant of every element of `sl[2,3]` = 1?

Comment: @psimeson: Yes, of course. This is guaranteed by `Mod[Det[#], p] == 1`.

Comment: But if I do `g= sl[2, 3]` and `Map[Det, g]`, I get `{-2, -2, -2, -2, -2, -2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -2, 1, -2, -2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 1, \
-2, 4, -2, -2}`

Comment: @psimeson:  Think of `Mod[Map[Det, sl[2,3]],3]` which results in `{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
  1}`. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: I am kinda confused here. I thought `sl[2,p]` is a group of `2X2` matrices with determinant 1. By that my understanding was each element of `sl[2,p]` has determinant 1. What am I missing here?

Comment: Also, how can I use `CayleyGraph` function to make a graph for small values of `p`?

Comment: @psimeson: (i) $SL(2,Z_p)$ lives in $Z_p$. (ii) As  
A. Kato says "Cayley graph is determined by the presentation (generators + relations) of the group; two different presentation of the same group usually gives non-isomorphic Cayley graphs. So you need to specify a presentation, not just the group". BTW, Maple has tools to this end.

Comment: i) Other than what is a group, I know nothing much about groups. So, I am sorry I didn't understand your first statement. Would you please explain it or point to resources where I can read about it? ii) I can pick a group element as a starting node, provide generators, and group operations which are matrix multiplication and mod. Even with these mathematica can't make Cayley graph?

Comment: See [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_linear_group) to this end as a first reading.